# Python logging - different logs from every instance of one class

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

Is there any way in python to get other logs from every instance of one class without necessitiy of modifying existing logs?

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger("my_module")

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def function(self):
        log.debug("My log!")

c1 = MyClass("first class")
c2 = MyClass("second class")
c1.function()
c2.function()`
```

I want to achive output like:

```
my_module - first class: My log!

my_module - second class: My log!
```

Is any way to do that without passing extra parameter to log.debug and configuring formatter? Like it's described in documentation: [DOCS](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug)

I am using aiomisc library, maybe there is some option to do this? I've looked at the documentation, but I don't see anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can fairly easily set up a different logger with a different name for each instance:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.log = logging.getLogger(f'{__name__}.{type(self).__name__}.{name}')

    def function(self):
        self.log.debug("My log!")
```

If your formatter is adding the logger name already, you will not need to do anything extra: the name of your logger is now going to be `my_module.MyClass.first class`, `my_module.MyClass.second class`.

If you want to send some custom messages to the module logger instead, you can add a function for internal use to your class:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def function(self):
        self.log(logging.DEBUG, "My log!")

    def log(level, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        log.log(level, self.name + ' - ' + msg, *args, **kwargs)
```

You might also take a look at using a [`logging.LoggerAdapter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#loggeradapter-objects).

Comment: Thank you, I considered that but read that is not a good  practice to set logger as a class attribute.

Comment: @TopTopek. It's not a class attribute here, is an instance attribute

Comment: Physicst Right, that's what i mean.

Comment: @TopTopek. I've added some alternatives